# How to add tables in footer of PDF in java using itext

Tags: java, itext

As I am new to *iText*. I don't know how to add table in footer of pdf using *iText 1.4*.

I already added table in header and it works fine. But in case of footer, it is not working properly.

Anybody please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, iText 1.4 is **SIX** years old. Is this intended? Secondly, you should edit your question and add the code your are using for the generation of the footer, so that people here can have a look at it.

Comment: Sorry ...I have replaced itext1.4 with itext5.2 but in that HeaderFooter class is not available. So how to add header using itext5.2

Comment: See my answer then. You might also want to edit your question mentionning you now intend to use the latest iText version.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the latest version of iText (5.2.x), headers and footers are best managed via Page Events.

See these [examples](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=221) taken from the iText in Action book.