# How to add a footer with multiple lines using iText 1.5.4?

Tags: java, itext

My question guys is how do I add a footer with multiple lines using iText 1.5.4
I know my question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562257/how-to-add-tables-in-footer-of-pdf-in-java-using-itext) but that question till now is not answered. Also I dont require the solution to use tables in a footer.

Basically what I want to achieve is something like this
[image: footer with multiple lines]

Comment: Did you see that OP rarely enters to SO and only has 1 of 3 questions with a real answer? You can't trust in him, but maybe in the posted answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the layout I wanted similar to the image I posted with my question using the code below.
Im not that familiar with itext so if anybody has a better way of doing this your comments and suggestions will be very much appreciated.
Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException{
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 70, 70);

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream("C:/pdfwithfooter.pdf"));
        document.open();

        document.add(new Paragraph(
                "Hello Body of the PDF"));

        /** Format Font **/
        Font fontFooter = new Font(FontFactory.getFont(
                FontFactory.HELVETICA, 6));

        /**
         * Format Table Cell Borders
         */
        // cell.disableBorderSide(Rectangle.BOX);
        Rectangle page = document.getPageSize();
        PdfPTable foot = new PdfPTable(4);
        PdfPCell footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
                "OUR DOCUMENT'S LEGEND", FontFactory.getFont(
                        FontFactory.HELVETICA, 6, Font.BOLDITALIC)));
        footCell.setColspan(2);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
        footCell.setColspan(2);
        foot.addCell(footCell);

        // 1st row
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("COX - COX", fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("EQ - Equipment", fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("OUT-XYZ - Out XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
                "ADJ-XX - Adjustment on XXXXXX XXXX", fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        // 2nd row
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("EB - Electric Bills",
                fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("T-BB - Transfer to Big Boat",
                fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("T-XXXX - Transfer to XXXX",
                fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("GX - Get XXXXXX", fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        // 3rd row
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
                "EXCEPTIONS - Invalid X Y VALUES", fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("R XX - Removal of XX",
                fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("T-X - Transfer of XXXX",
                fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
                "T-LX - Transfer of Leased XXXX", fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        // 4th row
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("LX - Leased XXXX", fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
                "T-TX - Transfer to TREE XXXXXXX", fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        foot.addCell(footCell);
        footCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
                "Adj-XXX - Adjustment Some Value",
                fontFooter));
        footCell.setPaddingLeft(15);
        footCell.setColspan(2);
        foot.addCell(footCell);

        foot.setTotalWidth(page.width() - document.leftMargin()
                - document.rightMargin());
        foot.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.leftMargin(),
                document.bottomMargin(), writer.getDirectContent());

        document.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to follow this example :

http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=103

You will be able to add whatever you want as header and footer. I've been using this in the past and was able to put a Table in the footer.

Note this `class HeaderFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper` and `public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)` in their example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have already read the examples from that link thats why I asked here because the example was too complicated and did not really answer my question, I was looking for something much straight forward to achieve the layout on the image I had posted along with the question.

Comment: Well sure this is complicated for one page document, but for more, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot with multiline header and footer in itext 5. Ultimately I switched to itext 7 and the implementation and examples made it very straight-forward. If upgrading is an option, I would just suggest using the latest version if you run into this problem.